# adding new resolution in multi monitor setup via xrandr

Tags: linux, nvidia, xrandr, multi-monitor

I have two monitors with different max. resolutions (2560x1440 and 1920x1080). In windows I am able to configure the max resolution for both monitors but in linux (manjaro, proprietary nvidia drivers and xrandr 1.5) is the resolution of the bigger one limited to 2048x1152. I read several questions/threads/articles how to add custom resolution via xrandr but none of these work for me. Here is my problem:

Output of xrandr:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3968 x 1152, maximum 16384 x 16384
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-I-2 connected 1920x1080+2048+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 478mm x 269mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+
   ... skipped few lines .... 
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94  
HDMI-0 connected primary 2048x1152+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm
   2048x1152     60.00*+
   ... skipped few lines ...                                                                              
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93                                                                      
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

I generate new custom resolution with cvt:

```
$ cvt 2560 1440 60
# 2560x1440 59.96 Hz (CVT 3.69M9) hsync: 89.52 kHz; pclk: 312.25 MHz
Modeline "2560x1440_60.00"  312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Now I want to create new resulution:

```
xrandr --newmode 2560x1440_60.00 312.25  2560 2752 3024 3488  1440 1443 1448 1493 -hsync +vsync
```

Output of xrandr looks now like this:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3968 x 1152, maximum 16384 x 16384                                           
DVI-I-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                               
DVI-I-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)                                               
DVI-I-2 connected 1920x1080+2048+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 478mm x 269mm                   
   1920x1080     60.00*+                                                                                      
   ... skipped few lines ...                                                             
   640x480       75.00    72.81    59.94                                                                      
HDMI-0 connected primary 2048x1152+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 553mm x 311mm               
   2048x1152     60.00*+                                                                                      
   ... skipped few lines ...  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DVI-I-3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
  2560x1440_60.00 (0x313) 312.250MHz -HSync +VSync
        h: width  2560 start 2752 end 3024 total 3488 skew    0 clock  89.52KHz
        v: height 1440 start 1443 end 1448 total 1493           clock  59.96Hz
```

If I want now to add this resolution to output HDMI-0 I get following error:

```
$ xrandr --addmode HDMI-0 2560x1440_60.00
X Error of failed request:  BadMatch (invalid parameter attributes)
  Major opcode of failed request:  140 (RANDR)
  Minor opcode of failed request:  18 (RRAddOutputMode)
  Serial number of failed request:  33
  Current serial number in output stream:  34
```

In the past I was able successfully use this method to setup my monitors as needed without any problem on different pc (notebook + ext. monitor, both with the same resolution). I would really appreciate any suggestions.

Comment: Might be a limitation of HDMI, it seems like many components can be the limiting factor if I understood the comments here correctly: http://superuser.com/questions/119755/hdmi-with-resolution-2560-x-1440-possible

Comment: I checked the link but I don't think so. As I write at the beginning, I have dualboot with windows and in windows it is possible to switch to 2560x1440.

Comment: My bad, missed that part.

Answer (score 0):

nVidia driver have a strict policy following EDID even they are buggy.

- It have an xorg options to ignore EDID and choose from all supported resolution by graphic adapter. Using one of:

  ```
  Option "UseEDID" "boolean"
  Option "ModeValidation" "NoEdidModes"
  ```

  May ignore partial features with:

  ```
  Option "UseEDIDFreqs" "FALSE"
  Option "IgnoreEDIDChecksum" "<con-1>, <con-2>"
  ```

  Or more advanced tweathing of EDID validation, see reference for supported values:

  ```
  Option "ModeValidation" "string"
  ```
- Also it has option to inject a corrected/modified copy of EDID. WARNING: It is dangerous, not all monitors are made robust.

  ```
  Option "CustomEDID" "<con-1>:</pathto/edid1.bin>; <con-2>:</pathto/edid2.bin>"
  ```

Reference:

- [NVIDIA Accelerated Linux Graphics Driver README and Installation Guide: Appendix B. X Config Options](http://us.download.nvidia.com/XFree86/Linux-x86_64/418.43/README/xconfigoptions.html)

Note:

By the way, verify if it has even retrieved EDID data using:

```
xrandr --verbose
```