# How to xrandr screen minimum and maxium resolution for Exceed-on-Demand (EoD)

Tags: linux, x11, xrandr, virtual-desktop

I am using a VDI called Exceed-on-Demand (EoD)  This thin client is able to resize the X desktop depending on the size of the monitor at the time you start the client.  However, you cannot resize the desktop afterwards.  I know that the RANDR extension is present and when I type xrandr this is what I get:

```
my-machine:~% xrandr
Screen 0: minimum 3840 x 1137, current 3840 x 1137, maximum 3840 x 1137
screen connected 3840x1137+0+0 975mm x 288mm
   3840x1137       0.0*
```

I have tried adding in new modes as described in [adding new resolution in multi monitor setup via xrandr](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/320300/adding-new-resolution-in-multi-monitor-setup-via-xrandr)

But that does not work; xrandr returns an error.

Notice that the minimum and maximum screen resolution are the SAME.  I believe this is my problem.  Does anyone know how to tell EoD to use a different screen size or how to change the minimum and maximum screen size for xrandr?